# ASP .NET website isn't loading | Error - HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found | IIS 10.0 Error

Tags: asp.net

ASP .NET website isn't loading: `Error - HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found | IIS 10.0 Error`.

[image]

Comment: Not very much to go on but I suspect that the file `.user.ini` doesn't exist on the server! Have you checked?

Comment: Domain: https://providentcapital.in/

Comment: Looks like the server is not setup correctly. It doesn't seem to be able to serve up any static files or even run any of the pages (looks like webforms) because of a conflict in the version of .NET - the server seems to have .NET Framework 2 available! (Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.9044; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.905) May be you should upgrade the server. Did you try any of the option presented in the screenshot? What did you find out?

Comment: actually, bro, I'm using Plesk hosting, and I've checked all options there, but unable to resolve it

Comment: Framework  Version 
3.5.30729.4926

Comment: should I go for 4.8.0?

Comment: What version does the app target? So long as it's .Net Framework running 4.8.0 should allow anything to work properly

Comment: 4.8.0 is showing redirection error